# R: Generate histogram from counts of data

Tags: r

Suppose I have vector `a`:

```
c(1, 6, 2, 4.1, 1, 2)
```

And a count vector `b`:

```
c(2,3,2,1,1,0)
```

I'd like to generate vector `c`:

```
c(1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 4.1, 1)
```

To call:

```
hist(c)
```

How can I build `c`, or is there a way to generate the histogram directly from `a` and `b`? Note the duplicates in `a`, as well as unequal spacing.

Require a vectorized solution. `a` and `b` are too large for lapply and friends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`?rep`

```
> rep(a, b)
[1] 1.0 1.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 2.0 2.0 4.1 1.0
>
```

---

Edit since I was curious!

```
a <- sample(1:10, 1e6, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:10, 1e6, replace=TRUE)

> system.time(rep(a, b))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.140   0.016   0.156 
> system.time(inverse.rle(list(lengths=b, values=a)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.024   0.004   0.028
```

Comment: Well i'll be damned, I didn't expect that!

Comment: A good *relative* speed up, but not exactly going to be waiting all day either way!

Comment: That speedup didn't happen in the direction I expected! But rep only takes 3 characters to type; Given that the absolute time is fast either way, number of characters wins out for me. So the accepted solution stays.

Answer (score 5):

Just for something different than `rep`:

```
> inverse.rle(list(lengths=b,values=a))
[1] 1.0 1.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 2.0 2.0 4.1 1.0
```

Comment: see the edit to my post.  your `inverse.rle` version is significantly faster!

Comment: @Justin, see my post - it shouldn't be and it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Some benchmarking and a faster solution. `rep.int` is a faster implementation of `rep` in the standard use case (from `?rep`)

```
rep.int(a, b)
```

I wasn't convinced on the benchmarking above

`inverse.rle` is just a wrapper for `rep.int`. `rep.int` should be faster than `rep`.  I would think that the `wrapper` component of `inverse.rle` should be slower than the interpretation of `rep()` as a primitive function

Some microbenchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(rep(a,b), rep.int(a,b), 
      inverse.rle(list(values = a, lengths =b)))
Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr      min       lq   median       uq
1 inverse.rle(list(values = a, lengths = b)) 29.06968 29.26267 29.36191 29.67501
2                                  rep(a, b) 25.65125 25.76246 25.84869 26.52348
3                              rep.int(a, b) 20.38604 23.31840 23.38940 23.69600
       max
1 72.80645
2 69.00169
3 66.40759
```

There isn't much in it, but `rep.int` appears the winner - which it should.

Comment: rep.int for 'internal'; not 'integer'; oh the R naming conventions... Thanks very much for the post using the microbenchmark tool; I learned a few things this evening for sure.